# Task never defined when using gulp series

Tags: gulp

I took this from [the Gulp documentation](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/series):

```
const { series, parallel } = require('gulp');

function clean(cb) {
  console.log("clean");
  cb();
}

function css(cb) {
  console.log("css");
  cb();
}

function javascript(cb) {
  console.log("javascript");
  cb();
}

exports.build = series(clean, parallel(css, javascript));
```

When I run this with `gulp build`, I get:

```
Task never defined: build
```

If I run `./node_modules/.bin/gulp build`, it works.

And if I change the exports to:

```
exports.build = css
```

and run with `gulp build`, then it works too.

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried this on the WSL (Linux, my default env), but also on Windows directly. Another developer on my team doesn't have this issue, although he is running on a Mac. I've also tried different versions of Node.

Comment: It's simply `exports.build`, not `module.exports.build`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't make a difference for me. I changed it, and I still have the same behavior.

Comment: `exports` and `module.exports` are the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating from gulp v4.0.0 to v4.0.1 fixes this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Issue is with local vs global version of gulp.

use 'node gulp build' or 'yarn gulp build' (if you are using yarn)

This will solve your issue.